# VSCode cannot find typescript .d.ts installed by npm

Tags: typescript

I installed with npm locally the d.ts package.

VSCode cannot find it, I have to move it to the root. Why ?

Comment: There are few possible options. Could you share your package.json and tsconfig.json?

Comment: @Drag13 finally by closing and reopening VSCode seems OK, thansk.